# ¿Porque se ejecuta varias veces un acción de un botón en un ventana en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, vistas, mysqlconnector.jar

soy un poco nuevo en java, estoy realizando un formulario con la intención de registrar a personas en una base de datos, solo que cuando ejecuto la acción la primera vez, realiza una solo vez la inserción en la base de datos sin problemas, pero cuando regreso a la ventana principal y vuelvo a la ventana del formulación para registrar a las personas, cuando vuelvo ingresar otra personas se registran dos veces el mismo registro en la base de datos y si repito la misma acción se registran n cantidad de veces el mismo registro en la base de datos.

Este el código de la conexión a la base de datos con acción de registro :

```
public void insertar(bd o) {
        try {
            conexion = new conexionaBD().conectar();
            sentencia = conexion.prepareStatement(INSERTAR);
            sentencia.setInt(1, o.getMatricula());
            sentencia.setString(2, o.getNombre());
            sentencia.setInt(3, o.getGrado());
            sentencia.setString(4, o.getDireccion());
            sentencia.setInt(5, o.getTelefono());
            sentencia.setString(6, o.getCarrera());
            
            sentencia.executeUpdate(); 
            resultado = sentencia.getGeneratedKeys();
            o.setID_Alumno(resultado.getInt(1));
                        
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error"+e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            cerrarConexion();
        }
    }
```

código de la venta de formulario:

```
public void crearVentana(){
        ventana = new JFrame("Registro de Alumnos");
        tex1.setText("Matricula");
        tex2.setText("Nombre");
        texto1.setText(null);
        texto2.setText(null);
        texto3.setText(null);
        texto4.setText(null);
        texto5.setText(null);
        texto6.setText(null);
        texto2.setBounds(100, 80, 200, 27);
        ventana.setSize(500, 400);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        tex1.setBounds(20, 50, 60, 14);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(tex1);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(texto1);
        tex2.setBounds(20, 90, 60, 14);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(tex2);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(texto2);
        tex3.setBounds(20, 130, 60, 14);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(tex3);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(texto3);
        tex4.setBounds(20, 170, 60, 14);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(tex4);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(texto4);
        tex5.setBounds(20, 210, 60, 14);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(tex5);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(texto5);
        tex6.setBounds(20, 250, 60, 14);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(tex6);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(texto6);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(boton1);
        boton2.setBounds(200, 300, 90, 20);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(boton2);
        this.boton1.addActionListener(this);
        this.boton2.addActionListener(this);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(ventana.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

código de acción del boton de Ingresar datos en la base:

```
if(e.getSource().equals(boton1)){
           alumno = new MYSQLUniversidad();
            String dato, dato1, dato2;
            dato = texto1.getText();
            dato1 = texto3.getText();
            dato2 = texto5.getText();
            int num, num1, num2;
            num = Integer.parseInt(dato);
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(dato1);
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(dato2);
            bd alum =new bd();
            alum.setMatricula(num);
            alum.setNombre(texto2.getText());
            alum.setGrado(num1);
            alum.setDireccion(texto4.getText());
            alum.setTelefono(num2);
            alum.setCarrera(texto6.getText());
            alumno.insertar(alum);
        }
```

código de bd:

```
public class bd {
    private int ID_Alumno;
    private int Matricula;
    private String Nombre;
    private int grado;
    private String direccion;
    private int telefono;
    private String carrera;
    
   public bd(){}
   
   public bd (int idalumno, int matricula, String nombre, int grado, String direccion, int telefono, String carrera){
       this.ID_Alumno = idalumno;
       this.Matricula = matricula;
       this.Nombre = nombre;
       this.grado = grado;
       this.direccion = direccion;
       this.telefono = telefono;
       this.carrera = carrera;
   }
   
   public int getID_Alumno() {
        return ID_Alumno;
    }
   
   public void setID_Alumno(int idalumno){
       this.ID_Alumno = idalumno;  
   }

    public int getMatricula() {
        return Matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(int Matricula) {
        this.Matricula = Matricula;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public int getGrado() {
        return grado;
    }

    public void setGrado(int grado) {
        this.grado = grado;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getCarrera() {
        return carrera;
    }

    public void setCarrera(String carrera) {
        this.carrera = carrera;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID_Alumno=" + ID_Alumno + ", Matricula=" + Matricula + ", Nombre=" + Nombre + ", grado=" + grado + ", direccion=" + direccion + ", telefono=" + telefono + ", carrera=" + carrera + ".\n";
    } 
}
```

código de regreso a la ventana principal:

```
public void ventanaPrincipal(){
        v1 = new JFrame("Universidad S Administracion de Alumnos");
        v1.setSize(600, 300);
        v1.setVisible(true);
        texto1.setText(null);
        texto2.setText(null);
        texto3.setText(null);
        texto4.setText(null);
        texto5.setText(null);
        texto6.setText(null);
        v1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        v1.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        v1.getContentPane().add(pb1);
        v1.getContentPane().add(pb2);
        v1.getContentPane().add(pb3);
        v1.getContentPane().add(pb4);
        this.pb1.addActionListener(this);
        this.pb2.addActionListener(this);
        this.pb3.addActionListener(this);
        this.pb4.addActionListener(this);
        v1.setDefaultCloseOperation(v1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    }
```

código de acción de regreso a la ventana principal:

```
if(e.getSource().equals(boton2)&& b==1){
           v1.setVisible(true);
           ventana.setVisible(false);
           ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(ventana.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);          
        }
```

Comment: Estás limpiando los campos de texto sólo al crear ventana o también al volver hacia detrás?

Comment: si también al volver hacia atras

Comment: La variable alumno de donde sale? Podrías compartir también el código de la clase bd?

Comment: intenta colocar la matricula como una primary key (que sea única por alumno) te deberá mandar un error cuando se vaya a duplicar. puedo Observar que en tu Método insertar(bd o) sera mejor que lo ingreses directamente desde los textos.setText... ya que son de clase y no es necesario parasarlos a una variable. Podría ser que allí es donde se estén duplicando... ya que se esta ingresando en el alum que envías y los textos. y es que la otra cuestión es que primero declaras como string y después esos mismos datos los pasas a int... Mételos directo. Intenta num= Integer.parseInt(texto1.getText());

Comment: Con el código que pones no es posible verlo, pero por la descripción al "volver para atrás" vuelves a ejecutar "crearVentana()", añades **otra vez** el listener, y al pasar un evento se ejecuta dos veces (es decir, la lista de listener de un botón tiene dos elementos, aunque esté repetido). Pon un "System.out.println" en el listener para comprobar cuántas veces se está ejecutando.

Comment: Hola @SergioGutiérrez acabo de subir el código de bd

Comment: cuantas veces llamas crearVentana()?

Comment: solo una vez cuando se oprime el boton de la ventanapricipal